# How to combine BETWEEN and AND in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, case, between

New SQL programmer here...

I'm building a CASE statement with some logic that integrates a BETWEEN statement and an AND statement (i.e. there are multiple conditions).  For whatever reason, all of the items are being assigned the ELSE value even though I know there are some that should fit into the other group.

I feel like I must be missing something pretty basic.  Any thoughts?

```
CASE
   WHEN ABC = 'A_' AND SHELF_LIFE BETWEEN 5 and 60 THEN 4.2
   ELSE 1
END
```

Here's some sample code:

```
SHELF_LIFE     ABC
224             CC
109             DD
80              AC
19              AA
28              BA
14              AD
```

Comment: Share some sample data and your expected results from the case statement given that sample data. Your `CASE` looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.  Just need to figure out how...Like I said I'm I newb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no `ABC = 'A_'`  do you mean `ABC like 'A_'`

Come on this is not working before the between.